# How to prove that a while always return a value in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I was using the `:|` operator and converted it to while, but now I don't know how to prove that the loop will always return a valid `x`. 
I had the following code:

```
method test(a : array<int>) returns (z : int)
  requires exists x. 0 <= x < a.Length && P(a[x]);
  ensures P(a[x]);
{
  var x :| 0 <= x < a.Length && P(a[x]);
  return x;
}
```

and I changed it to:

```
method test(a : array<int>) returns (z : int)
  requires exists x. 0 <= x < a.Length && P(a[x]);
  ensures P(a[x]);
{
  var x := 0;
  while (x < a.Length) {
    if (P(a[x])) {
      return x;
    }
    x := x + 1;
  }
}
```

How should I prove it? I did a PoC on rise4fun: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/LpRZA.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like adding a invariant to the loop is enough:

```
method test(a : array<int>) returns (z : int)
  requires exists x. 0 <= x < a.Length && P(a[x]);
  ensures P(a[x]);
{
  var x := 0;
  while (x < a.Length) 
    invariant exists x' :: x <= x' < a.Length && P(a[x']);
  {
    if (P(a[x])) {
      return x;
    }
    x := x + 1;
  }

  assert false; // be sure that it does not reach here
}
```